# How to search etree using lxml like BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml, beautifulsoup

Suppose I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FeedType xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://foo.com/bar" xsi:schemaLocation="https://foo.com/bar https://foo.com/bar/arr.xsd" value="Type">
    <ElementName value='Type'>
        <DataIWant>
            stuff
        </DataIWant>
        <DataIWant>
            other stuff
        </DataIWant>
    </ElementName>
</FeedType>
```

And I want to get everything in the `ElementName` tag.

In Beautifulsoup, one could call

```
soup.find_all('ElementName')
```

Which would return a tree with `ElementName` as the root.

How can I do this in lxml?

Comment: lxml has a findall method... have you tried to use it yet?
http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#findall

Comment: using `root.findall('ElementName')` returns None.

Comment: @shivsn If you try using the answer there, you'll find that it returns `None` or `[]` incorrectly for my xml. 

sample code: 


`xml = ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><FeedType xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://foo.com/bar" xsi:schemaLocation="https://foo.com/bar https://foo.com/bar/arr.xsd" value="Type"><ElementName value="Type"><DataIWant>stuff</DataIWant><DataIWant>other stuff</DataIWant></ElementName></FeedType>')`
 
   
   `root = etree.fromstring(xml)`
    `print(root.findall("ElementName"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lxml` has a [`findall` method](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#findall), which can be used.

However, the XML document contains a default namespace, and therefore searching for a plain `ElementName` tag won't find it - you need to specify the namespace:

```
root.findall('foobar:ElementName', namespaces = {'foobar': 'https://foo.com/bar'})
```

If you don't want to specify the namespace, you can use an XPath query that will ignore the namespace and just find elements whose "local name" is `ElementName`:

```
root.xpath("//*[local-name() = 'ElementName']")
```

Comment: Is it possible to ignore the namespace, or have it be parsed automatically, like in BeautifuSoup?

Comment: @Dr, you can ignore the namespace using XPath - please see my updated answer

Comment: Is it possible to do something like 
`root.find_all('ElementName' , {'href' : 'stuff''})`? 

As in, select only ElementNames for which the href attribute is 'stuff' ? Sorry to be so demanding, but the lxml documentation is rather difficult to understand.

Comment: Yes, XPath supports this - you can use `root.xpath("//*[local-name() = 'ElementName' and @href = 'stuff']")`  the `lxml` documentation probably doesn't include an XPath tutorial, but you can research it independently of lxml :)